# NPE checked by StringUtils.isNotBlank still causing eclipse @NotNull warning

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, notnull, jsr305

I am using **@NotNull** annotation,
as you can see I am using:

> StringUtils.isNotBlank()

to check NP, but I have still Eclipse warning there. If I use

> oldlink != null

it wont show warning.

Does anyone know what can be problem when using **apache commons StringUtils** ?

[image: NPE warning]

Comment: There is no problem. When you use the ``!=null`` comparison, the compiler sees that you check for null. When you use a call to some method such as ``isNotBlank()``, the compiler has no idea that this method checks for null as well. That's why you still receive the warning. But that is a compiler warning and you can just ignore it.

Comment: I have similar problem with Apache `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()` in IntelliJ IDEA 13. It shown potential NPE even though this method checks for it. And I think later version of IDEA don't do that and actually consider what's going on inside apache method.

Comment: @f1sh I know but they could improve this thing, as isNotBlank() method has a null check, so they could introduce some exceptions when using `apache commons`

Comment: @ToKra that's not an easy thing to do. That would require the compiler to look up that code. In this case, it's a static method an can be done. With non-static methods it's impossible for the compiler to do that reiliably.

Comment: @f1sh I did not mean to look into method, Eclipse team knows Apache Commons libs, so they could make some exceptions into framework, which would not require any compiler involving... just quessing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only this help, `null check` and the use of `StringUtils.isNotEmpty()`, even `StringUtils.isNotBlank()` does the same:

[image]